# Linux commands within bat file - Aliasing

Tags: linux, windows, batch-file, command

I seem to be having an issue.
I'm trying to write a batch file that uses Linux commands such as `rm`, `mv`, `clear`, and `cat` within a Windows batch file, but the catch is I can't seem to figure out what I need to do in order for the Windows command line to recognize that when I type in `mv` I want it to move a file for me, or `rm` to remove a file of course.

So far all I have figured out is that I could possibly use `__DOSKEY__` but it doesn't work in batch files or with parameters (doh!). Thus, all I have gotten so far is:

```
@echo off
mv dummy.txt
```

Now my question is how do I get the Windows command line to recognize that `mv = move` ? Everytime I run the file it just gives me a blank command line.

I know this may sound stupid but my experience is more on the Linux side of the command line than the Windows side, and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Batch file commands need to match shell builtins or programs installed on the system.  So your options are to use the CMD.EXE builtin commands (`move` instead of `mv`, `del` instead of `rm`, `type` instead of `cat`) or else install a set of POSIX commands on your windows machine.  For example, Git for Windows and Cygwin both come with large sets of Linux-like tools.

Comment: Type `doskey /?` to see how to specify parameters. In batch see `call /?` for batch parameters. So a batch fil called mv.bat would have `@move %1 %2`.

Comment: Is it possible to not use Cygwin or Git for the conversion of these commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internal cmd commands cannot be aliased. For external commands, you could create hardlinks, but "move" for example is an internal command.